# Fully customised wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: Search from website]

http://www.nekretnine-oglasi.me here is website...
This website is on wordpress... I need search like this on picture, but I dont know how to make it...

1. option is to choose Category
2. option is City
3. option is Area(quadrature, size)... it is From - To
4. option is Price... From - To

Is there any plugin or some piece of code to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of different plugins you can use in WordPress.

When I've just started working with `WordPress`, I was using visual form builders and tried couple of others plugins.

[**Visual Form Builder**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/)

Another way is to use the existing code for this form. You can use Inspect Element in Chrome or Mozzila and take the `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` code for this template.

**UPDATE:**

[**Code on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qy7toefy/1/) - here is the copy of that form.

Comment: I dont need html code... I need php code that would do search... I already have form made... that is my website, and now I need php to make it works

Comment: Then you should be more specified in asking the question. You confused me.. Then I can suggest you to use go through advanced search form php tutorial or use the WP plugins.

Comment: I can point what you should do then: 1. create script.php and clean all input variables from search page. 2. connect to the database and make a select statement ".. WHERE grad = '$grad' .. 3. protect your form from mysql injection.

Comment: I know to do that... I know do it with core PHP... But what about wordpress, because that website is on wordpress

Comment: What is the problem? Create additional page and add it to WP, insert code there, and make an output page whatever you want. If you know PHP it will take you 15 min.

Comment: Ok... I am going to try... But I think I would have problems with wordpress templating...
Can I put wordpress code into file with name for example myfile.php
??

Comment: Sure play around it, WP is easy it will just take a bit of time to get used to the structure .

Comment: I made custom named page but I got this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in pretraga.php on line 1